# How to get local time zone for an email sent from another country in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: email, timezone, microsoft-graph-api, timezone-offset

When you make a call on Microsoft Graph API for a specific email message, all DateTimeOffset are in UTC time : createdDateTime, sentDateTime...

I would like to know the local time zone of an email **when it was sent** from some place. Example : I am french, travelling to US, and sending an email during my stay : the time zone of the 'sentDateTime' should be different, but it remains in UTC, losing this information. Is it possible to find this information using Microsoft Graph API somewhere else ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment this isn't possible. All of the times are returned by Graph (and the Outlook REST API) as zulu.

There is however a UserVoice request to ["Allow Microsoft Graph API to return mail headers"](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/18159700-allow-microsoft-graph-api-to-return-mail-headers) that would also help with this scenario. *These are actively reviewed so each vote counts (hint hint).*